# API works when normally called in chrome but not in Postman

Tags: android, rest, dart

API: https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY&expiryDate=17-Jun-2021

The above API works fine(gives back a json) when called in chrome but when called using Postman, no json gets fetched.

Other Values for expiryDate:

"expiryDates": [ "10-Jun-2021", "17-Jun-2021", "24-Jun-2021", "01-Jul-2021", "08-Jul-2021", "15-Jul-2021", "22-Jul-2021", "29-Jul-2021", "05-Aug-2021", "26-Aug-2021", "30-Sep-2021", "30-Dec-2021", "31-Mar-2022", "30-Jun-2022", "29-Dec-2022", "29-Jun-2023", "28-Dec-2023", "27-Jun-2024", "26-Dec-2024", "26-Jun-2025", "24-Dec-2025" ],

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Doesn't work for me in ChrEdge, it gives "resource not found". Does it require some kind of auth/cookie ?

Comment: Oh! Sorry. Forgot to mention, doesn't work on weekends. This is one of India's Stock Exchange's Index. As the market is closed on weekends, the API doesn't return anything. But I was checking it yesterday(Friday) and it wasn't working